# My onclick does not work right the way it should be

Tags: javascript, php

I have this function

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <=9; $i++){
print("<div id='cover'>");
for ( $j = 1; $j <= 9; $j++){
    if($i % $j == 8 || $i < $j || $i == $j){
        print("<div class='colors' onClick='hello($i, $j)'>");
    } else {
        print("<div class='pinks' onClick='hello($i, $j)'>");
    }
    print($i ."+". $j ." ");
    print("</div>");
}
print("</div>");

}
?>
```

Which produces a bunch of div with numbers on it. I want to be able to click on it, and show the result of adding two numbers. 
I have this JavaScript function for that

```
function hello(r, t)
{
     $("div.colors, div.pinks").html(r+t);
}
```

but I do not know how to get only the one div i click on. How can I do that?

Comment: Since the problem seems unrelated to PHP, please post the produced html instead of the php script.

Comment: ... Don't select all of them. You're setting the `click` handler in each element already, why select it (or them, in this case) again? Also, boo-hiss for inline JS. Consider using `data-` attributes instead, and less obtrusive JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to calculate the element on which the user has clicked, then the method should be more like this:

```
function calc(element, r, t)
{
    element.innerHTML = r+t
}
```

while the method call ofc would be:

```
<div><a href="#" onclick="calc(this,3,2);">3+2</a></div>
```

See this fiddle for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/m9wkr0vz/

---

To allow more complex calculations without providing methods for every combination, you could use javascripts ability to evaluate expressions given:

```
function calc(element)
{
    element.innerHTML = eval(element.innerHTML);
}
```

with

```
<div><a href="#" onclick="calc(this);">(7+1)/(2+2)</a></div>
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u20bgx83/